# Server wait during flask app socketIO script

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I'm trying to create a time delay within a server-side script of a flask web socket app.

Ultimately, I want the server to be handling many simultaneous requests, and to be able to emit back to the client two packets with a fixed time interval between.

When I use `time.sleep(x)` between two `flask_socketio.emit` statements, the client receives the socket emit events together, after the sleep has been completed.

How can I achieve `Emit X; wait Y seconds; emit Z` in a python flask application?

**Server-side code excerpt:**

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, emit
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
@socketio.on('ping')

def ping(appState):
    """send 2 pings, between a time interval"""
    room = appState["sessionID"]
    emit('serverPingResponse', {'room': room, 'msg':"Ping Received by Server"})
    time.sleep(5)
    emit('serverPingResponse', {'room': room, 'msg':"2nd time-delayed ping"})
    return
```

**Client-side code excerpt:**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
socket.on("serverPingResponse", function(msg){
      // listen to server ping and print the message to console
      let d = new Date();
      console.log("ping received at "+d.toLocaleTimeString(), msg)
    });
```

**Console Output**

```
pinging server...
ping received at 10:43:14 AM 
Object { room: "wvdhj01f3p", msg: "Ping Received by Server" }
ping received at 10:43:14 AM 
Object { room: "wvdhj01f3p", msg: "2nd time-delayed ping" }
```

Desired output would be for the first ping to be received at `10:43:09` and the second at `10:43:14`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `time.sleep()` function, which I'm guessing is blocking your server. Try using `socketio.sleep()` instead, which would do a cooperative sleep compatible with the async framework that you are using (eventlet, gevent).

Comment: Perfect.  I .was mistaken in thinking that my flask app automatically `greened` the `time` module